# Получение html с web страницы

Tags: html, objective-c, парсер, macos, синтаксический-анализ

При помощи какого инструмента можно получить html содержимое страницы, что бы потом его парсить?

Есть ресурс при просмотре кода страницы отображаются только скрипты и css. Сама страница постоянно обновляется, а именно чат и верхний фрейм. Мне нужно получить именно то, что сейчас отображается на экране.
Ну, допустим, в чат пришло сообщение, в котором есть слово "для" или любое другое. Вот мне нужно получать данные сообщения.

Данный сайт я гружу в нативном браузере который сделал на основе WebView.

Я бы погуглил но не до конца понимаю, как это искать.

Comment: [http://habrahabr.ru/post/163979/](http://habrahabr.ru/post/163979/) и [http://habrahabr.ru/search/?](http://habrahabr.ru/search/?q=HTML+%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80) для понимания

Comment: Не совсем то что мну нужно было. Но сейчас пытаюсь реализовать с помощью AFNetworking. Правда что бы получать данные приходится постоянно отправлять запросы на обновление страницы.